# Combining color and shape in an R plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly

Is this possible. I want to do something like

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c(3,5,2,6,8,1),c=c("p","p","q","r","r","r"),
             d=c("v","v","w","v","v","v"), stringsAsFactors= F)


df %>% 
plot_ly(x=a,y=b,mode="markers",type="scatter", color=c, 
      marker = list(          
       symbol=d)
  )
```

But the different symbol I want on third data point is not appearing

[image]

Also is it possible to set the symbols to be other than default

TIA

Comment: ggplot(data=df, aes(x=a, y=b, shape=d, color=c)) + geom_point(); ggploty() would work

Comment: Thanks. It would without the typo :) However, I would ideally like to use native plotly if there is a solution

Comment: have you tried this df %>% plot_ly(x=a,y=b,mode="markers", symbol=d, color=c)

Comment: I thought I had - but obviously not. i thought the symbol was within marker. Kinda got lost in the voluminous reference material. If you want to put as answer then i will accept

Comment: @MLavoie Actually that gives me a symbol difference but I lose the color differentiation!

Comment: see edits on my answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copying my comment here:

If you want to stick with `plotly`, you can use:

```
df %>% plot_ly(x=a,y=b,mode="markers", symbol=d, color=c)
```

You can also define your symbols with:

```
symbols = c("cross", "square", "triangle-down")
```

EDIT:
You could create an interaction and then use this new factor as a symbol. You will have only one legend (I don't think having two legends is possible with native `plotly`).

```
df$Int <- interaction(df$c, df$d)
df %>% plot_ly(x=a,y=b,mode="markers", symbol=Int)
```

But you could also use `ggplot2` using:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=a, y=b, shape=d, color=c)) + geom_point()
ggplotly()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . JAR it is ggplotly(). If anyone has a native plotly solution, please feel free to contribute :)

Comment: With the newest version `plotly_4.5.2` it should be able: `df %>% plot_ly(x=~a,y=~b,type="scatter", mode="markers", symbol=~ d, color=~c)`